# Accessibility issue on IOS. aria-expanded not detected by voiceover

Tags: ios, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I am encountering accessibility issue on iOS using voiceover.
    "aria-expanded" not reading expanded when bootstrap button drop-down is expanded.

Reference link:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/dropdowns/

Using the same button drop-down for my website

Please, can anyone come up with the solution.
Specifically with IOS*

Thanks in Advance ;)

Answer (score 3):

That's how voiceover handles dropdown menus.  The example on the bootstrap site is correctly toggling the `aria-expanded` attribute.  The change of state is announced with NVDA and JAWS but VoiceOver chose not to announce it.  However, when I navigate to the button, VO does say "double tap to expand", so it does know about the attribute.  As long as you are setting the right ARIA attributes and changing their values appropriately, you are ok.  It doesn't matter if VO doesn't announce it correctly.  (Well, it **does** matter to the end user, but the problem is with VO and not your site.)  With regards to accessibility, you are good.